# user paste a hyperlink and picture into a text area

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that has in internal email system . There is a text area for the body of the email. but what I need to do is allow the user to paste a link or picture into the area. can this be done ? or is there a script etc.. 
Any help would be appreciated !

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

TinyMCE is very popular WYSIWYG editor, it will convert the text area into a javascript based editor. The resulting content in the text area is html which can be sent through e-mail. Note that many e-mail viewers have very shoddy html/javascript/css support.